# не работают кнопки на java для андроид приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

не могу понять почему не работает, делаю приложение на андроид 4.4 в java, три кнопки и текст на экране, каждая кнопка меняет текст, но почему то не работает, последние три строки подчеркивает красным и не запускается код. помогите пожалуйста

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView logo_text;
    private Button button_enter;
    private Button button_instagram;
    private Button button_facebook;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logo_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logo_text);
        button_enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
        button_instagram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_instagram);
        button_facebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button_enter: logo_text.setText("ВХод"); break;
                    case R.id.button_instagram: logo_text.setText("Инстаграмм"); break;
                    case R.id.button_facebook: logo_text.setText("фэйсбук"); break;
                }
            }
        };

    }
    button_enter.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button_instagram.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button_facebook.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}
```

Comment: Ваши кнопки находятся вне метода `onCreate`

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло, всего пару дней на java, туплю сильно(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переместите в `onCreate`

```
    button_enter.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button_instagram.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button_facebook.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло, всего пару дней на java, туплю сильно(